# How do I set the screen transitions for all screens in Android?

Tags: android, animation, translation

In my app I want to switch between all screens/activities using a fading animation. Can I set something, possibly in the manifest, that would allow this to take place when going between any screen/activity?

----- edit -----

I've updated my files based on Hamad's suggestion. Removing the `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar` caused me to lose my styles on some elements like padding, margins, background, gravity, text color, etc. So I did the following to fix the styles but now it seems to be running the "jump to next screen" and the "fading to next screen" together.

screen_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0"
        android:duration="1000" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

screen_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0"
        android:duration="1000" >
    </alpha>
</set>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="ScreenTransition.Activity" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"> 
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/screen_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/screen_out</item>
</style>

<style name="ScreenTransition" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ScreenTransition.Activity</item>
</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
 android:name="com.library.books.MainActivity"
 android:label="home"
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
 android:theme="@style/ScreenTransition" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I do have an activity called baseActivity that I use to hold methods used across all activities. I'm not against putting something there and simply calling it on a button press.

Comment: [overridePendingTransition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#overridePendingTransition(int,%20int)) called after startActivity() or finish() will do the trick. You should create a method in your base activity and call it instead of android's startActivity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this:
  1. create a `<style>` in `res/styles.xml`, like this:

```
<style name="YourAnimation.Activity" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity"> 
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/your_in_down</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/your_out_down</item>
</style>
```

2.Then you can apply the style to a theme, in the same file:

```
<style name="YourTheme" parent="android:Theme.Translucent">
   ...
   <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/YourAnimation.Activity</item>
</style>
```

3.And finally apply the theme to your activities in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:theme="@style/YourTheme" />
```

Comment: That got my fading working! However, that removes the "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" causing some styles I had in place (margin, padding, background, and others) to be removed. I added it to the the parent="" in the styles.xml and but causes to animations to run: the "jump" from Halo.light and the "fade" from my animation. I'll update my question with code from my files.